# C3 Align Title to the left

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I am new to C3 (and D3) having spent all my time using Zingcharts.

I want to move the chart title to the left edge.

I have tried the css and nothing seems to move. I can change the size and color but not the alignment or the position.

```
.c3-title {
  font-size: 26px;
  fill: green;
  text-align: left;
  }
```

and the C3 for adding the title.

```
title: {
         text: 'My Title',
 },
```

[image]

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either

1. Use the position attribute when setting the title

   `title: { text:"TITLE", position: "upper-left"},`
2. For more fine-grained control, you need to change the x attribute on the .c3-title text element for the chart

http://jsfiddle.net/cbd3fs41/

Best place is to change it in the onrendered callback in the chart configuration

```
onrendered : function () {
    d3.select(this.config.bindto).select(".c3-title").attr("x", 50);
}
```